# Select an Attribute with unique numbers at the end

Tags: jquery, class, css-selectors

I have a situation where I am sorting through a list of blog posts in a custom CMS.  Each blog post is wrapped in a `<li>` and there are multiple posts on the page.  I have code that puts in a sharethis button set on each blog post.  Unfortunately all the class names for a blog post start with "post".  For example;

```
<div class="blogList">
     <ul>
          <li class="post1">
               <h2 class="postTitle">A Sample Title</h2>
               <div class="postDescription">Some sample content</div>
          </li>

          <li class="post2">
               <h2 class="postTitle">A Sample Title</h2>
               <div class="postDescription">Some sample content</div>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I was sorting through this with an ".each" on the li but that ended up adding it to the lists that are included in any post content itself.  So I want to only add this once onto the actual parent li of each individual blog post.

What I'm trying to do is add it only to the `<li>` with a class of "post" and then a number.  I can't just look for post since it also will add it onto any other item with the class of "post" as it's starting name.

How can I select only the elements with only the class of "post" and a number?  So I would want to find only elements in the above example of li.post1, li.post2 .  All other elements would be skipped.

I'm doing this in jquery and I feel like I'm close but just can't seem to get over this hump.

Below is the code example I'm using in it's entirety.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Run through the page and find each individual blog post
        $('.blogList li [class^="post"]').each(function () {

            //Grab post title & encode any quotes so they don't mess up generated HTML
            var postTitle = $.trim($(this).children(".postTitle").text().replace('"g, "'));

            //Grab URL from the anchor element inside the h2 element (will not grab correct link in admin mode)
            var postLink =  location.protocol + '//' + location.host + $(this).children("h2").find("a[href]").attr('href');

            //Add "share this" HTML elements to the bottom of the post
            $(this).append(
                 '<div class="st">' + 
                    '<span  class="st_twitter" displayText="Tweet" st_url="' + postLink + '" st_title="' + postTitle + '"></span>' +
                    '<span  class="st_facebook" displayText="Facebook" st_url="' + postLink + '" st_title="' + postTitle + '"></span>' +
                    '<span  class="st_linkedin" displayText="LinkedIn" st_url="' + postLink + '" st_title="' + postTitle + '"></span>' +
                    '<span  class="st_email" displayText="Email" st_url="' + postLink + '" st_title="' + postTitle + '"></span>' +
                    '<span  class="st_blogger" displayText="Blogger" st_url="' + postLink + '" st_title="' + postTitle + '"></span>' +
                    '<span  class="st_sharethis" displayText="ShareThis" st_url="' + postLink + '" st_title="' + postTitle + '"></span>' +
                '</div>'
            );  
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a more specific class selector. This rule should get what you need:

```
$('div.blogList>ul>li[class^="post"]')
```

That will get you only direct child li's with a class of post* that are direct children of a UL that is a direct child of a div with a class of blogList.